# Estimating a survival probability in R (2)

Tags: r, kaplan-meier

Following [Brian Diggs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26247/estimating-a-survival-probability-in-r/26291#26291)'s answer, I have tried to estimate some survival probability in `R`. However, the result is wrong (`1` instead of `0.9`) and I do not understand what is going on... Can you explain me?

```
> time
 [1] 1.38103330 2.14191380 1.47271212 0.02703924 0.34921793 3.01005383 1.01132532 0.09546903 0.44729971 1.12909544
> event
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> km <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1)
> surv <- stepfun(km$time, c(1, km$surv), right=FALSE, f=0)
> surv(min(time))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Here you use the left-continuous version of the Kaplan-Meier estimate (option right=FALSE), so the result is correct.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: But according to the 'help' page, "For the default, right = FALSE, f = 0, fn is a cadlag function, i.e., continuous at right, limit (‘the point’) at left.".

Comment: Strange - you could also try approxfun() with option method="constant"

Comment: Can I have an example with approxfun() ?

Comment: Try this:   surv <-  approxfun(km$time, km$surv, method="constant", yleft=1)

Comment: Moreover I remember I already had a similar problem, but I do not remember well... instead of km$time, try to use sort(time), does it work ?

Comment: It looks to work with 'sort(time)'. This is a bit wierd... but many thanks!

Comment: In passing do not use "time" as a variable name ! This is the name of a R function and this can be dangerous !

Comment: Ok... thanks. By the way, the solution with "sort(time)" may fail in case of ties...

Comment: Then type sort(unique(time))